# (PIG) environment variable for local execution

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bash

I am trying to run a `.pig` script locally. The document [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PigTutorial) says to set up an environment variable.

I am not sure how we can do that. I am using Mac Yosemite. What I have done currently is in .bash_profile I have added the following line:

```
 export PIGDIR=/Users/name/Pig/pig
```

When I now run

```
java -cp $PIGDIR/pig.jar org.apache.pig.Main -x local script1-local.pig
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.pig.Main
```

Could anyone suggest where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you source the .bash_profile after adding the variable? Does echo $PIGDIR print out the correct value? Is the problem still there if you run PIGDIR=/Users/name/Pig/pig java -cp $PIGDIR ...

Comment: echo $PIGDIR gives the correct value. There is a problem in the alternative solution you suggested as well.

Comment: Got the error, the correct path should have been export PIGDIR=/Users/name/Pig/